# Unity: how to create a material property drawer for a custom asset type?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a custom asset of type

```csharp
[System.Serializable]
public class Ranges: ScriptableObject
{
  public Vector4[] minPoints;
  public Vector4[] ranges;
}
```

A corresponding shader has two uniforms defined

```csharp
half4 _coeffMins[25];
half4 _coeffRanges[25];
```

I can set the uniforms using `Material.SetVectorArray`, however, I'd like to be able to directly drag my custom asset into a slot in the property inspector of materials using the shader.

There is [MaterialPropertyDrawer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyDrawer.html) however it seems like [MaterialProperty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialProperty.html) the OnGUI function gets passed does not support arrays.

There is [MaterialPropertyBlock](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html) which does support arrays, but I didn't figure out how this can be used to create a custom property drawer.

So, how can I create a material property and corresponding property drawer that takes my custom scriptable object as type?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to **create custom editor for the material property drawer**, and then **add a new Object field**, that would accept your object, **and hook the data** on the change to that Material to change Material.SetVectorArray based on this data.

```csharp
    [CustomEditor(typeof(Material))]
    public class MyMaterialEditor : UnityEditor.Editor
    {
        Ranges source = new Ranges();

        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            var material = ((Material) serializedObject.targetObject);
            if (material.name == "DryWallPainted_Mat") // or other way to identify your material in editor
            {
                source = (Ranges) EditorGUILayout.ObjectField((Object) source, typeof(Ranges), true);
                if (source != null && source.ranges != null && source.minPoints != null)
                {
                    material.SetVectorArray("minPoints", source.minPoints);
                    material.SetVectorArray("ranges", source.ranges);
                    EditorUtility.SetDirty(material); //important
                }
            }
            DrawDefaultInspector();
        }
    }
```

**Result:**

[image]